# Replacing square flush mount light falling out of ceiling

Tags: lighting

[image]

Okay, so my husband and I are avid DIYers, and we have just a few things left to do on our 1977 ranch renovation. One of those is replacing the hideous ceiling light fixtures in our hallway. After I scraped the popcorn ceiling one of these square dogs of fixtures started to come loose. It looks like the original hole was cut too big. Regardless, they are awful and I would like to replace them with something simple that would not require repairing the giant 11.25 inch square hole in two places in the ceiling of my hallway. I'm hoping something like this Lithonia 12 inch light would work. Advice please? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Replacing that light seems like a solid plan, but I think you still need to repair the sheetrock and put in a standard ceiling electrical box.  The hard part of drywall repair is taping the seams and floating, texturing, etc.  The good news is that you don't need to do any of that.  Do the absolute minimum job of replacing the square of drywall and cut a new hole in the repair for the round ceiling box.  The repair needs to be strong, but it doesn't have to be pretty.

The new fixture will cover the rough repair, but you will still have a standard light installation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the light comes in 12", 15", or 20". I know the upsizes aren't ideal, but it might be an option as well as the side view (see C dimension) shows that there is still a lip between the housing and the diffuser which could mean that the housing itself might not cover the hole.

[image: Light fixture dimensions]

Is there any existing electrical box holding the light up? As long as you have one, regardless of the hole, you should be golden for installing the new light. If there isn't a box, you'll need to install one.. but you don't necessarily need to patch the ceiling.

Below is the installation diagram included with your new light selection. It again doubles the "install a box if you don't have one and you should be good" answer.

[image: Installation diagram]